# Calling a module inside another module

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am calling a method in a module from another module and am getting a weird error.

```
 require 'nmap'
 ...    
 module Enumeration::Hostnames
   def reverse_dns ip_addrs
     ...
     ip_addrs.each do |ip_addr|
        list = ListScan.test ip_addr #this is the problem
        ...
     end
     ...
```

ListScan is in the nmap file.

```
  module ListScan
  def ListScan.test target
    target = '-sL ' + target
    ListScan::parse_results Nmap::Parser.parsescan('nmap',target)
  end
  ...
  end
```

The error is `const_missing': uninitialized constant Enumeration::Hostnames::ListScan (NameError) on the line ListScan.test ip_addr.

Why is it assuming that ListScan is in the Enumeration::Hostnames module? Mixing in ListScan to Hostnames didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby searches for constants starting from the current context, which in this case is `Enumeration::Hostnames`.

Try using

```
::ListScan.test ip_address
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. Its kind of odd, never had this issue with modules in the Ruby API